# How to attach event handlers to controller in MVC | JavaFX

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller

I am having trouble understanding how to apply the mvc pattern with JavaFX.

Here are my questions with respect to the code below, since I need to follow the pattern given in the code:

a) How can I attach an event handler of the button which is present in my ViewA to the code in my ControllerA (specifically, `attachEventHandlers()` method). For example, I want my button to populate the comboBox in ViewA with the results of `getModelItems()` method from controller.

Note that the method `getModelItems()` is private.

b) I would have multiple buttons and event handlers in my view. How will I bind each one of them uniquely to the controller?

c) I want to invoke `setName(String name)` on my model in the controller, and the parameter I want to pass is the selected value on the comboBox in viewA. How can I achieve this?

Thank you so much for any help!

Below is the code referred in the description.

Controller:

```
import model.ModelA;
import view.ViewA;
public class ControllerA {

    private ViewA view;

    private ModelA model;

    public ControllerA(ViewA view, ModelA model) {
        //initialise model and view fields
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        //populate combobox in ViewB, e.g. if viewB represented your ViewB you could invoke the line below
        //viewB.populateComboBoxWithCourses(setupAndRetrieveCourses());

        this.attachEventHandlers(); 

    }

    private void attachEventHandlers() {
    }


    private String[] getModelItems() {

        String[] it = new String[2];
        it[0] = "0";
        it[1] = "1";

        return it;
    }

}
```

Model:

```
public class ModelA {

    private String name;


    public Name() {
        name = "";
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name = " + name;
    }

}
```

View:

```
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

//You may change this class to extend another type if you wish
public class ViewA extends BorderPane {
    public BorderPane bp;

    public ViewA(){
        this.bp = new BorderPane();
        ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
        Button button1 = new Button("Populate");
        bp.setTop(button1);
        bp.setBottom(comboBox);

    }
}
```

Loader:

```
public class ApplicationLoader extends Application {

    private ViewA view;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //create model and view and pass their references to the controller
        ModelA model = new ModelA();
        view = new ViewA();
        new ControllerA(view, model);   
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        //whilst you can set a min width and height (example shown below) for the stage window,
        //you should not set a max width or height and the application should
        //be able to be maximised to fill the screen and ideally behave sensibly when resized
        stage.setMinWidth(530); 
        stage.setMinHeight(500);


        stage.setTitle("Final Year Module Chooser Tool");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(view));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You add delegates to your ViewA to allow for access:

```
public class ViewA extends BorderPane {
    ComboBox comboBox;
    Button button1;

    public ViewA(){
        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        button1 = new Button("Populate");
        setTop(button1);
        setBottom(comboBox);
    }

    // Add delegates for all functionality you want to make available through ViewA
    public ObservableList<String> getItems() { return comboBox.getItems(); }
    public void setOnButton1Action(...) { ... }
    public void setOnButton2Action(...) { ... }
    ...
}
```

You can go as broad or as narrow as you like, based on how much you want to manage through ViewA.